# How to "kubectl get ep" in deployment.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have a kubernetes deployment using environment variables and I wonder how to set dynamic endpoints in it.

For the moment, I use

```
$ kubectl get ep rtspcroatia
NAME          ENDPOINTS         AGE
rtspcroatia   172.17.0.8:8554   3h33m
```

And copy/paste the endpoint's value in my deployment.yaml. For me, it's not the right way to do it, but I can't find another method..

Here is a part of my deployment.yaml :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: person-cam0
  name: person-cam0
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: person-cam0
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: S2_LOGOS_INPUT_ADDRESS
          value: rtsp://172.17.0.8:8554/live.sdp
        image: ******************
        name: person-cam0
```

EDIT : And the service of the rtsp container

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: rtspcroatia
  name: rtspcroatia
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8551
    targetPort: 8554
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: rtspcroatia
```

Can you help me to have something like :

```
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: S2_LOGOS_INPUT_ADDRESS
          value: rtsp://$ENDPOINT_ADDR:$ENDPOINT_PORT/live.sdp
```

Thank you !

Comment: You'd probably have to use a tool like [`kustomize`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize).

Comment: Why not creating a service for the rtsp deployment and referencing it in the cam0 deployment?

Comment: **d4nyll** : How Kustomize can help me to put the result of a command in a variable ? I am really new to Kubernetes and even newer on Kustomize.  

**Thomas** : The rtsp deployment already has a service called `rtspcroatia`. I didnt mentionned it cause I thought `kubectl get ep rtspcroatia` was referring to a service.. I can set the value like this ?
`value: rtsp://rtspcroatia/live.sdp`

Comment: Why you need loadbalancer type service for `rtspcroatia`? Can't it be just `clusterip` type service. And refer that service using `rtspcroatia.namespace.svc`

Answer (score 1):

You could set dynamic ENDPOINTS values like "POD_IP:SERVICE_PORT" as shown on below sample yaml code.

```
   containers:
   - env:
     - name: MY_ENDPOINT_IP
       valueFrom:
           fieldRef:
               fieldPath: status.podIP
     - name: S2_LOGOS_INPUT_ADDRESS
       value: rtsp://$MY_ENDPOINT_IP:$RTSPCROATI_SERVICE_PORT/live.sdp
```